# Can I get things like nvm to persist on my WSL installation? Anything installed on WSL disappears when I kill the terminal session

Tags: linux, terminal, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

From my day job I'm used to using mac when doing local web app development, using javascript, react, node, next.js, etc.

I'm on my home windows machine and have WSL installed to get a more mac like environment. However it seems whenever I install NVM, restart the WSL session and then try to use NVM it's gone. Does WSL not act as a persistent linux system on my PC? Does it start up a fresh copy every time?

Comment: Is nvm truly 'gone', or are you just getting 'command not found'? Have you read all the notes? https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I am getting 'command not found'. What notes are you referring to? When I install nvm it tells me ` Close and reopen your terminal to start using nvm or run the following to use it now:` I can run the commands it provides and start using nvm immediately, but when I close and reopen my terminal I am back to getting 'command not found' when trying to use nvm

Comment: I am referring to the `readme.md` document that I gave a link to.

Comment: I beleive we've established NVM isn't "gone" (ie uninstalled) just the session is no longer running as you expect.  Is this correct?   Please edit your title appropriately then.  thx.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean closing the terminal windows but WSL is still running in background I think the issue is that NVM runs as a foreground app.  So when you close the terminal you close the console session and that kills the app in the foreground.

If that's the problem then you can either:

a)  Stop closing the terminal.

b)  Run your app in a `screen` or `tmux` session.   Then it will keep running when the main console session is closed or interrupted.

Option b) screen or tmux, is basically creating a "virtual console" so that when you close the terminal (or in any Linux, log out of the console), the virt console persists so any jobs or processes within keep running.

Comment: so I guess I'm not understanding what WSL is correctly. I was hoping to use it just like I use the terminal on my mac while doing web development. On my mac I do it through VS Code (and on my PC), I just open a terminal and do the things I need to do, nvm and my other terminal apps are always there no matter how many times I close the terminal, close VS Code, or reboot my machine. Is that not going to be possible if I'm trying to use WSL the same way on my Windows PC?

Comment: You're right, you are slightly misunderstanding.   OS X is a unix-like OS, as is Linux. Windows is not.  So to do WSL 'magic' Windows essentially creates a virtual machine and runs a flavor of Linux inside.  There's some extra tricks to make the integration better and stuff but that's the basics.  A simple VM.  On your Mac, the terminal is just a command line into the user session you're already logged in as when you logged in the gui.  That session isn't destroyed till you fully log out of the gui.  But here, Windows and the WSL machine are really 2 separate machines.    ===1/2

Comment: So when you close the Terminal for WSL, there's no one "still logged in" and anything in foreground will be terminated.  The VM keeps running though afaik so that anything that is a service in the WSL machine will keep running.

So it'll work but you'll have to make some adjustments as you're working in one session on one machine on your Mac but 2 "separate" machines in the Win/WSL environment.   ---2/2